# what does replace and amp10 here stands for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var value = elem.value;
value=value.replace(/\n/g,"amp10;");
```

Can someone please explain what is amp10 and /\n/g ? what does it stand for?

Comment: [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

\n = regex for [new line](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_newline.asp)
"amp10" is what it should replace new lines with ;)

so e.g. your element.value holds 10 line breaks:

```
elem.value.replace(/\n/g,"amp10;");
```

will replace all line breaks with amp10 which would result in:
"amp10;amp10;amp10;amp10;amp10;amp10;amp10;amp10;amp10;amp10;"

Cheerio :)

Answer (score 0):

The the first part of the replace body (before the comma) (...) is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

`\n` stands is a unix 'new-line' character.

`/g` stands for replace globally.

"amp10;" is the value you are replacing all new lines with.

I have a feeling you are looking for something like this:

```js
var value = "some long string\nwith lots of stuff in it\n";

$('#original').html(value);

value=value.replace(/\n/g,"&amp;");


$('#new').html(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Original</h1>
<span id="original"></span>
<h1>Transformed</h1>
<span id="new"></span>
```

Comment: what is the value of amp10 here?

Comment: amp10 is a string literal.  meaning, it is exactly as you define it.

Comment: i want to insert $#^&(all special chars )in the text box. If i enter test%@ it should take the complete value including special characters? how can i achieve this using replace function?

Comment: That should just work. I don't know what you're trying to solve here.  You should update your question with more information.